# How to add a triangulate modifier and apply it?

Tags: python, modifiers, objects

Im trying to check if the selected object has a specific modifier, adding the modifier if it doesn't exist, and then applying all the modifiers:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.object

modifs=[]
for modifier in obj.modifiers:
    modifs.append(modifier.type)

if 'TRIANGULATE' not in modifs:]
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='TRIANGULATE')

for modif in modifs:
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier=modif)
```

Code above adds the modifier if it isn't present but it doesn't apply the modifiers to the object. If I paste `bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier=modif)` into the python console it applies the modifier. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try *bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')* instead of the last 'for modif in modifs' loop above.

Comment: Also in your script you should 'modif.append(modifier.name)' not 'modifier.type'. What is unclear: shoud the triangulate modifier be applied?

Comment: Nah, type is nice in case there is another trianulate modifier @lemon

Comment: @brockmann, was talking about the first loop, not the triangulate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list doesn’t contain the newly added triangulate modifier (if there is one). Also, it seems necessary to apply by name, not by type. The following works for me:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.object

modif_types = [ modifier.type for modifier in obj.modifiers ]

if 'TRIANGULATE' not in modif_types:
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='TRIANGULATE')

modif_names = [ modifier.name for modifier in obj.modifiers ]

for modif in modif_names:
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier=modif)
```